# Navigation dropdown menu hover tooltip does not work as expected

Tags: html, css

Link to my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/nqo2zwor/1/)

I tested my css with using only div and p, which when i hover on div, p dropdown some paragraph and i can move around p without the dropdown disappear, here's my tested [code](https://jsfiddle.net/my25nej1/).

I tried tested with `.nav-item:hover .nav-content { max-height:400px; }` and it didn't work, only if i use the + selector.

Comment: Are you trying to show tooltips on dropdowns, or are you just trying to create some sort of dropdown menu/list?

Comment: yes i'm trying to create dropdown menu/list, when hover on the list of menu, the sub meun list dropdown, and my problem was that even ever i try to hover on my sub menu list, the dropdown disappeared

Comment: Okay. Just so you know, that's just a drop down menu, :hover is implied, and this has nothing to do with tooltips.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say :3

Comment: It was just a hint to the title of the post, where you used hover/tooltip. This has nothing to do with tooltips (which are the text that shows up when you hover over something with a title-attribute), or styled info-containers that pops up when you hover specific elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of use the `:hover` on the `a` element you should use the `:hover` on the `li` element:

```
li:hover .nav-item {
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

li:hover .nav-item ~ .nav-content {
  max-height:400px;
}
```

Here is the example:

```css
/*Navigation Bar */
/*Css*/

body, html {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.nav-main {
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  height:60px;
  color:white;
}

.nav-main .logo {
  float:left;
  height:30px;
  padding:18px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.nav-main > ul {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  float:left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-main > ul > li  {
  float:left;
}

.nav-item {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px 20px;
  height:60px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited, a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-content {
  position:absolute;
  top:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:red;
  max-height: 0px;
}

.nav-content a {
  color:black;
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-sub {
  padding:10px;
}

.nav-sub ul {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-sub ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:5px 0;
}

li:hover .nav-item {
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.nav-item:focus {
  background-color:white;
  color:red;
  transition: 0.2s
}

li:hover .nav-item ~ .nav-content {
  max-height:400px;
}
```

```html
<title>Football Match</title>
<!-- below are bootstrap cdn link, jquery and js -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <!-- Navigation bar -->
  <div class="nav-main">
    <div class="logo">WebsiteLogo</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-item" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-item" href="#">Matching</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
          <div class="nav-sub">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Match Query</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Match Creation</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Match Manager</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="nav-item" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Btw, there's another problem when i do the hover on my sub menu, the padding doesn't cover all the size of the menu list, and after i change from hover on :a to li:, the focus does not shown correctly, which the focus should be on top of hover when click on it, but instead it only shows the hover color.